# Why is C# calling the wrong overload?

Tags: c#, overriding

I have following code that really **does** *funny* stuff:

```
class Parent {
    public virtual void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> list) {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)");
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    public override void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> list) {
        Console.WriteLine("Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)");
    }

    public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<object> list) {
        Console.WriteLine("Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<object>)");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `DoSomething` method in `Child` is overridden correctly.

The output of the following code is very unexpected:

```
...
Child c = new Child();
var list = new List<string> { "Hello", "World!" };
c.DoSomething(list);
...
```

Prints `Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<object>)`

Whereas assinging a `Parent` reference to `c` generates the correct output:

```
...
Parent c = new Child();
var list = new List<string> { "Hello", "World!" };
c.DoSomething(list);
...
```

Prints `Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)`

Why does this *happen*?!

Comment: Well, I have tested your code in VS2008 using unit test. And I get `Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)` as a result in both.

Comment: @Draco: He must be running in .NET 4.0/C# 4.0 for this behavior to take effect, since `List<string>` is compatible with `IEnumerable<object>` with the new variance support introduced.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior as well.. VS2010 .NET 4.0 C# and always got "Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)" as output. You must have more code than that, causing this behavior.. please post your full code and we'll see for ourselves.

Answer (score 11):

It happens because the C# compiler obeys the spec :)

The specification says that if any method declared in a derived type is applicable, any methods *originally declared* in a base class (even if they're overridden in the derived type) are removed from the set of candidates.

Now because you're using C# 4 (presumably) there's an implicit conversion from `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>` so your `Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<object>)` overload is applicable, and the compiler never really considers the one using `IEnumerable<string>`.

I have an [article about overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) which goes into this and some other oddities.

I advise you not to overload across type hierarchies - it's confusing.

Comment: I assume there are good reasons behind this, but I think it's an unfortunate part of the specification. It breaks with the principle of least surprise.

Comment: This is referred to in the [C# Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc), part 7.5.5.1 - Method Invocations, and there's also a comment about this in section 7.4.3 - Overload Resolution: *For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (§7.3), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (§7.5.5.1).*

Comment: but what about the second one, why in second one it calls the inherited item?

Comment: @SaeedAlg: Because then *overload* resolution (compile-time) doesn't know anything about the methods on Child. At *execution* time the overridden method is picked as the implementation of the signature picked at compile time.

Comment: Because the compiler only uses the type of the object that it knows about, and it only knows that the object supports what's in Parent, and thus only has one method available when resolving the method invocation. If you had used the new `dynamic` type of C#/.NET 4.0, the method call would've been resolved at runtime, and would've fallen back to the object-based overload.

Comment: @Lasse: For what it's worth, I can see the point behind rejecting methods which aren't declared at all by the child class, but I believe that overridden methods shouldn't be chucked out. The idea is to prevent the brittle base class problem, where adding a method to a base class breaks callers of the child class, when the child class didn't know about the change. If you're overriding the method, you clearly know about it, so that shouldn't apply.

Comment: I know about brittle base classes and the problems they give, I'm just not sure if that is a bigger problem than the one we're currently having. Of course, the whole point is moot since this is not going to change now. Of course, since I don't know all the reasons behind this, there might be others in addition to the brittle base class problem, so *in my opinion* I think it's unfortunate. It might, however, be the best solution. That is, I highly suspect it is :)

Answer (score 0):

posible soulution, try:

```
class Child : Parent {
    public override void DoSomething(IEnumerable<string> list) {
         Console.WriteLine("Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<string>)");
    }

    public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<object> list) {
        if(list is IEnumerable<string>){
            DoSomething((IEnumerable<string>)list);
            return;
        }
        else  
            Console.WriteLine("Child.DoSomething(IEnumerable<object>)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lasse,

you wrote

> Because the compiler only uses the type of the object that it knows about, and it only knows that the object supports what's in Parent, and thus only has one method available when resolving the method invocation.

I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying, but in the second case, since the instance is an instance of Child and the method being called is virtual, the method resolution is done at run time and not compile time, and in fact it is the child's method that is being called.

As regards method resolution rules. Shouldn't it choose a more specific method? I know it's a moot point at this stage. in 3.5 and 2 it would pick the more specific method.